# Google timeline chart (with numbers), starting time

Tags: javascript, charts

I've made a timeline chart, where I dont get to use specific dates/times, but I get value in minutes. Thats why I changed an example from type 'date' to 'number', and I multiply my value by 60000 (# of miliseconds in a minute).

http://jsfiddle.net/6M2sH/606/

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'Value1', 0*60000, 10*60000 ],
      [ 'Value2', 10*60000, 15*60000 ],
      [ 'Value1', 45*60000, 61*60000 ],
      [ 'Value4',  15*60000,  45*60000 ],
      [ 'Value3',  45*60000,  450*60000 ],
      [ 'Value4',  375*60000,  450*60000 ],
      ]);

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }
```

This example is almost fitting, except the timeline starts from 1:00am for some reason. I would like it to be 0:00.

How do I set up the starting date?

Comment: I later realised if I use number instead of date for a timeline graph, that the number is an actual timestamp. With some more testing of bigger numbers, I've realised that the timeline actually starts on 1st of January 1970.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to use *DATE* type for this situation; 
If you can use **x*60*60** gives you seconds.

If you use **x*60** gives you minutes and then you can insert it wherever you want;

For insert **seconds** use  `new Date(0,0,0,0,0,yourSecond)`

For insert **minutes** use  `new Date(0,0,0,0,yourMinutes,0)`

```
 dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Value1', new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0*60*60), new Date(0,0,0,0,0,1*60*60) ],
          [ 'Value2', new Date(0,0,0,0,0,1*60*60), new Date(0,0,0,0,0,1.5*60*60) ]
          ]);
```

[DEMO JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6M2sH/607/)